# Android Layout Shake (AppBarLayout and RecyclerView)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

When I use a massive content `AppBarLayout` with a `RecyclerView` in a `CoordinatorLayout`, there are two questions:

1. If your finger sweep up on `AppBarLayout` quickly, the layout can't scroll to `RecyclerView` smoothly and `AppBarLayout` will be bounce back.
2. If your finger sweep up on `AppBarLayout`, then sweep down on `RecyclerView`, the Layout will be shake, cause `AppBarLayout` has inertia by first action of sweep up.

How can I solve this issue on without changing the structure of the layout, or how can I define a `Behavior` at `AppBarLayout` to solve this issue? Cause I can solve it by the layout of without `AppBarLayout`, but that not I wanted.

[My Project Address](https://github.com/thirtyyuan/DiaryPageDemo)

Thx!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/diary_cp_check_in_time"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="I'm AppBarLayout"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/diary_info_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: please update @Brad Yuan if the answer helped...

Answer (score 0):

`recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` use this in your code... As you are setting behavior of your recyclerView `appBarScrollingBehavior` the recyclerView will scroll in a nested manner. Setting the `nestedScrollingEnabled` as false will allow you to scroll the recyclerView freely.. and you also wont get the `shaky` effect (both upwards and downwards)..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18736322)

Comment: I think the above answer will solve both of his problems ..!!

Comment: Add some further explanation as to why it fixes the problem then. Single line answers saying 'Use this code' tend to get flagged as low quality. Just a bit of explanation about why this solves the problem will result in a much better answer for the OP and other people who come across the question.

Comment: I have added the explanation ..!!

Comment: If it solved your problem just update that your question is answered ...!!

Comment: sorry, it's did, I thought `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` can't solve my problem, I know if I use NestedScrollView to wrap a RecyclerView, it's should be helpful. Cause NestedScrollView's Nested scrolling is enabled by default, and it's conflict with RecyclerView' `nestedScrollingEnabled = true`. But my problem isn't for this. It's between AppBarLayout upwards event and RecyclerView downwards event. But thanks for your help again! :D

Comment: *I dint get you...'If it solved you are welcome.. and please press the tick mark on the left of my answer :p '